# google scripts onedit -> email trigger for range produces an email for each edit

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I know that what is happening is by-design but I'm trying to figure out how people deal with this - tried a few different approaches but I think I'm not thinking about it the right way ( I'm more of a bash scripter :) ).

I have a Google Sheet with a script that does onEdit on a range of cells: if any cell in the range is edited, an email is sent. GOOD!

Now, if someone edits, say 5 cells in that range, then 5 emails get sent. BAD!

So it *seems* like I need a way to have each script run "know" about each other and only send an email after some amount of time after the first cell is edited?

I looked at this for a clue but setting a flag would prevent other edits...
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails#section2

I have to imagine this is a common thing to figure out but it's not coming to me.

thanks guys for any ideas, much thanks
JL

Comment: What would be the ideal time frame / frequency for you to be informed by email ?

Comment: we want an email sent when any one of the cells in range are edited, not on a timer, BUT we don't want an email for each individual edit. - one example could be that the email waits to send ALL the edits 5minutes after the first cell is edited. - I can't seem to wrap my head around that each time it triggers it would start that 5min timer separately :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the script PropertiesService to save a timestamp. For example the script below will only send an email once a day.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/

```
var settings = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
var lastEditEmailDate = settings.getProperty('lastEditEmailDate');
var today = new Date().toDateString();
if (lastEditEmailDate != today) {
 /*send the email*/
 settings.setProperty('lastEditEmailDate', today);    
}
```

Comment: yeah I think that's the best I'm going to get as a bash guy LOL - THANK YOU!! --update: my reputation is too low to give you a +1up :(